# Ethereum Token Nam Redundancy

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I have created a ERC20 token in ethereum blockchain with token name as TestToken and Symbol as TTT. Now how can I ensure that others cant create a token with the same name and same symbol? Is there is any way to ensure the redundancy in token name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience no, the trick is that you have a unique contract address you can use.  So there can be an unlimited number of tokens with the same name, the trick is that they will each have their own address.  Also you will get more responses if you use https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/